# WiFi роутер с умным распределением скорости

Tags: wifi, роутер, lan

Имеется домашний интернет GPON от МГТС, с их собственным wifi роутером.
Для онлайн игры без лагов нужны стабильные 50 кбайт/с
Когда на параллельном подключении начинается загрузка объёмных файлов, начинаются лаги...

Правильно ли я понимаю, что сам МГТС тут не при чём, и нужен нормальный роутер с неким "умным" распределением трафика, чтобы не просаживал меня ниже какого-то порога, в связи повышенными запросами с другого подключённого устройства?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понимаете правильно, но вот добиться такой приоретизации будет не совсем просто:

1. Нужен роутер, [который умеет помещать трафик в очереди и делать шейпинг](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/trafficshaper/capabilities.html).
2. В этом роутере нужно настроить очереди так, чтобы трафик с других машин обрезался только при наличии пакетов с определенным QoS
3. На вашей машине нужно помечать пакеты от игрушки этим QoS
4. Начать можно с банального - подключиться к роутеру кабелем.